# Is it possible to use windows Ink (handwriting recognition) to analyze an image?

Tags: image-processing, windows-7, ocr, image-recognition

Is it possible to use the MS Ink API to analyze a scanned image of handwriting, or does it only work with tablet pen input?

If it is possible, where is the relevant documentation?

Answer (score 2):

No, its not possible.

Windows Ink is technology that uses information from the writing process, such as pen up and down, as well as direction of movement. this makes handwriting recognition relatively easy, but only because it can get the live writing data.

Analyzing previously written handwriting is very different and much more difficult, and requires machine learning. In this case it is kind of using the same method of recognition as humans use. check out the developments in Intelligent Character Recognition and Intelligent Word Recognition. It requires a lot of processing power and thats why services such as google goggles have to send the image to a 'trained' machine, and even then it cant really read handwriting well. its cutting edge technology, not ready at all for mass deployment.

Answer (score 1):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms698159(v=VS.85).aspx

This application demonstrates how you can build a handwriting recognition application.The Windows Vista SDK provides versions of this sample in C# and Visual Basic .NET, as well. This topic refers to the Visual Basic .NET sample, but the concepts are the same between versions.

And you must also investigate the main class InkAnalyzer.

---

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb969147(v=VS.85).aspx

This sample shows how to use Ink Analysis to create a form-filling application, where the form is based on a scanned paper form.

Comment: Looks like the form is scanned, but the data has to be entered with a tablet pen or something similar.  I was hoping for a scanned-in handwriting OCR feature (or hack).